# How to throttle current jobs in airflow?

Tags: concurrency, throttling, optimistic-concurrency, airflow, database-concurrency

I am a newbie to Airflow. But I am now working on how to throttle current jobs in Airflow. Is there someone that knows a little about concurrency or throttling in Airflow. Any suggestions could be helpful.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to throttle tasks in a dag, you need to define its "concurrency" parameter.

> "concurrency" defines how many running task instances a DAG is allowed
> to have, beyond which point things get queued.

If you want to throttle tasks globally, look into this lines of the config file

> The amount of parallelism as a setting to the executor. This defines
> the max number of task instances that should run simultaneously
> on this airflow installation
>
> parallelism = 32

And

> The number of task instances allowed to run concurrently by the scheduler
>
> dag_concurrency = 16

The first is global, the second is the concurrency default value for all dags